# Is Jinja2 documentation out of date?

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I am getting 2 errors by doing simple things that follow the documentation here http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/ :

```
{% if lang == 'fr' %}
   bonjour
{% elif lang == 'en' %}
   hello
{% endif %}
```

TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'elif', expected 'else' or 'endif'

and

```
{% extends "skeleton.html" %}

{% block a_name %}
{{ super() }}
I am extended
{% endblock %}
```

where skeleton.html contains 
    {% block a_name %}
    hi I am skeleton
    {% endblock %}

TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'super()

Any clue on that ? Thanks

Comment: Is this a Django template?

Comment: no, a jinja2 template

Comment: Jinja2 doesn't throw `TemplateSyntaxError`s, only Django does. The two formats look similar, but they're completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using jinja2 with Google App Engine. Well, I *thought* I was doing so, but a closer look to the exception and the file stack trace, showed that it said "django".

For future reference, doing

```
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

will make appengine render the template with django. Even if it says jinja2/latest in app.yaml under libraries.

You must import jinja2 and explicitly use `template = jinja2.get_environment...` to make it work.
See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates?hl=fr for more info

Thanks for setting me on the track @Blender