# Jinja2 install issue

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I am getting the following error message when attempting `{% set foo = 42 %}` in my html template. The template works fine when the `set` is not used.

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'
```

Below I have added the full session log as suggested in comments.

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=15093 --admin_port=8018
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2016-05-14 18:36:26,513 devappserver2.py:762] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-05-14 18:36:26,696 api_server.py:204] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56265
INFO     2016-05-14 18:36:26,701 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:15093
INFO     2016-05-14 18:36:26,704 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8018
ERROR    2016-05-14 18:37:48,778 webapp2.py:1528] Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brian/googleapps/lastturn/views.py", line 187, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 91, in render
    t = _load_internal_django(template_path, debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 165, in _load_internal_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 279, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 332, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error(token, "Invalid block tag: '%s', expected %s" % (command, get_text_list(["'%s'" % p for p in parse_until])))
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'
ERROR    2016-05-14 18:37:48,784 wsgi.py:279] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brian/googleapps/lastturn/views.py", line 187, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 91, in render
    t = _load_internal_django(template_path, debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 165, in _load_internal_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 279, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 332, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error(token, "Invalid block tag: '%s', expected %s" % (command, get_text_list(["'%s'" % p for p in parse_until])))
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'
INFO     2016-05-14 18:37:48,792 module.py:812] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Below I have added the revisions I made to my  `views.py`. The commented out lines indicate the original  jinja2 environment statements. These revisions are in response to suggestions made in comments. But I still get the same error message which seems to suggest jinja2 is not being used.

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
#jinja_environment = \
#jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR))

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(
        self,
        filename,
        template_values,
        **template_args
        ):
#template = jinja_environment.get_template(filename)
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Below is the base.html template.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the "heart" of the actual template. By "heart", I mean I have left out the guts because this is just a test.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <center>
        <h1>Create or edit your own Blog</h1>
      </center>
      {% set foo = 42 %}
      {{ foo }}

    {% endblock content %}
```

[This answer suggests to me that jinja2 is not installed (properly?).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799710/)

Is there some other part of installation that I have to change?

[This answer shows more input about **ipython** installation,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843950/) but I am using **google-app-engine** which may be different. The listing below confirms that Jinja2 2.8 is installed.

```
server:~ brian$ pip freeze
Warning: cannot find svn location for setuptools===0.6c12dev-r85381
all==0.0.6
altgraph==0.7.1
atari-py==0.0.17
bdist-mpkg==0.4.4
bonjour-py==0.3
caller-module==0.0.9
Django==1.3.1
include-server===3.1-toolwhip.1
Jinja2==2.8
macholib==1.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
mod-python==3.3.1
modulegraph==0.8.1
numpy==1.11.0
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==3.2.0
public==0.0.0
py2app==0.5.3
pyglet==1.2.4
pyobjc-core==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.3.2a0

pyOpenSSL==0.12
PyRSS2Gen==1.0.0
python-dateutil==1.5
PyYAML==3.11
render==1.0.0
requests==2.9.1
six==1.10.0
Twisted==11.0.0
xattr==0.6.1
zope.interface==3.5.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
server:~ brian$
```

Comment: May we see your template or at least the complete `block` surrounding your suspect statement?

Comment: Yes, please look at revised question.

Comment: Syntax is correct for jinja2. But your app appears to be using django templates, not jinja2 ones - syntax is slightly different. See @Blender's comments to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306640/is-jinja2-documentation-out-of-date.

Comment: Might not be correct, tho - at least GAE's `jinja2-2.6` **does** raise TemplateSyntaxError - it's present in its `jinja2/exceptions.py` file. The full traceback may still indicate precisely which templates are actually used.

Comment: Dan, I have revised the question again. I suspect the problem  is that the Templates subdirectory in my  gae project is not being correctly passed to the jinja environment. The full traceback only mentions django, not jinja. Do you see any possible fixes?

Comment: You should place the full traceback in the question as well, to set things straight. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with django, can't tell how to configure it to use jinja2 templates. I don't think your suspicion is right - it would be if you'd be using the jinja templates, but you're not. Only **after** you get the jinja2 templates used (i.e. seeing them in the traceback) you may need to worry about why they'd be upset :)

Answer (score 0):

After much help via comments to my original question, and to much stumbling, I have finally answered my question. I was confused by both webapp2 and Jinja having a template.render() but they are different.

template.render() from webapp seems to require 2 parameters -- the path and the template name --  and my current code uses this format. However, I want to use Jinja2 where template.render() requires only 1 parameter -- the template name.

According to the [google docs for using Jinja in the guestbook app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/generating-dynamic-content-templates) the following format was shown.

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
```

But it turns out that does not work well with my chosen BaseHandler class which puts templates in their own subdirectory, "templates". Instead I used the following code where TEMPLATE_DIR replaces **file** in the "loader=" sentence  .

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR ),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
```

Btw, I no longer import the webapp `template`. And I use the following style in my "get def"s.

```
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render( template_values))
```

So, although the question asks "Jinja install issue",  it was not exactly the install that was problematic, rather I had difficulty integrating  Jinja with my existing directory structure.